# Group query in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get No. of Tickets per day for this I used this code:

```
@num=Ticket.group("date(created_at)").count
```

This worked properly now I don't want No. of Tickets per day for only previous 15 days, for this I used the following snippet:

```
 to=Date.today
 from = to-15
 @num=Ticket.group("date(created_at) from .. to").count
```

But this showing some errors, can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: Try this: `Ticket.where("created_at > ?", 15.days.ago).group("date(created_at)").count`

Comment: Do you want previous 15 days from today's date?

Comment: thanks that worked, I'd be more thankful if you could tell me what I've done wrong

Answer (score 1):

`"group by date(created_at) from .. to"` is invalid SQL, even if `from`/`to` were to be interpolated in there.

You can use

```
Ticket.where(created_at:(15.days.ago .. Time.now)).group('DATE(created_at)').count
```

`group` and `count` are designed to be applied to a scope for this reason - just select objects you want to count, then group, count etc.